# Recursive Functions help on displaying reverse numbers

Tags: c++, function, recursion

Here's the entire problem:

Write and test two recursive function void `reverseDisplay1(int value)`
and `void reverseDisplay2(int value)` that implement the following
 definitions:

A:  “To display the reverse of a number, display the last digit
followed by the other digits in reverse order”,

B : “To display the reverse of a number, display in the first digit
after the reverse of the second and all following digits.”

I want to mainly know what **b)** is trying to say. I understand that **a)** is trying to say that if I run the following `reverseDisplay1(123)` I'll get `321`. Let me know if I'm wrong on that and what **b)** is trying to get me to do.

Comment: Does it *really* say *"...display in the first digit..."* in your problem text ? I mean, *exactly*, word for word ?

Comment: You should get the same result with both, they are just asking for two different recursive implementations.

Comment: @WhozCraig Yes, the entire quote is verbatim.

Comment: @Red Wow. See if you can get extra credit for repairing your instructor's grammar. That's dreadful. Regardless, I concur with miradulo. The first clause of each question is identical, so the output will be the same. I *suspect* one of them (the first) just dumps digits only, while the other builds an actual `int` that would be a reverse-digit representation of the input. In your case, the actual number `321` would be generated, then simply printed. Honestly, though, it's hard following that instruction, so I would ask for clarification form the instructor regardless.

Comment: @WhozCraig Nah they don't do extra credit, unfortunately. I thought for the first one it wanted me to print 321 as an int and the second one to print 231 or 213 or even 132 whatever the correct way is. Thank you for your insight.

Comment: I suspect it's a clumsy way to make you explore right and left folds (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fold_(higher-order_function)).

Answer (score 1):

It's two different ways of doing the same thing. The first way is to print the last digit and then recursively print the rest of the number (in reverse). The second way is to print the digits except for the first one recursively (again, in reverse), and then add the first digit to the end.

Answer (score 0):

They mean the same: the reversal of 12345 to 54321.
The difference is in the way/algorith to implement the requirement.

- A: “To display the reverse of a number,

  1. display the last digit *followed by*
  2. the other digits in reverse order”,
- B : “To display the reverse of a number,

  1. display in the first digit *after*
  2. the reverse of the second and all following digits.”

So:

```
fA:
    lastDigit = ...
    otherDigitsNum = ...
    restReversed = fA(...);
    display ...

fB:
    firstDigit = ...
    otherDigitsNum = ...
    restReversed = fB(...);
    display ...
```